# Difficulty instantiating a subclass [object has no attribute]

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-multithreading, member-functions

I get two types of errors when I try to start or initiate the member function `temp_controll` from the subclass `Temperature_Controll`. The issue is that the while loops are started in a new thread.

I am having trouble passing the modbus client connection to the member function.

```
 AttributeError: 'ModbusTcpClient' object has no attribute 'modbus'
```

I don't understand the problem in its entirety, because I assumed I would inherit modbus.client from the main class?

The second problem was, when I comment out rp and want to access a member function from the main class "database_reading", I get the following error:

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'database_reading'
```

How can I execute the subclass method via a second thread?

```
class Echo(WebSocket):

    def __init__(self, client, server, sock, address):
        super().__init__(server, sock, address)
        self.modbus = client

    def database_reading(self)
        do_something()
        return data


class Temperature_Controll2(Echo):

    def __init__(self, client):
        super(Temperature_Controll, self).__init__(client)
        self.modbus = client
    
    def temp_controll(self, value):
        #super().temp_controll(client)
        while True:
            print("temp_controll")
            rp = self.modbus.read_coils(524, 0x1)
            print(rp.bits[0])

            self.database_reading()
    

def main():
    logging.basicConfig()
    with ModbusClient(host=HOST, port=PORT) as client:
        client.connect()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        print("Websocket server on port %s" % PORTNUM)
        server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', PORTNUM, partial(Echo, client))
        
        control = Temperature_Controll2.temp_controll
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=control, args=(client, 'get'))
        t2.start()
        
        try:
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=server.serveforever())
            t1.start()
        finally:
            server.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is a minimal example of my code, the thread t1 is executed without any problems. I have little experience with OOP programming, maybe someone here can help, thanks!

Comment: You have many problems here. Firstly you are not instantiating `Temperature_Controll2` in your `main()` function. Secondly, if you were to (eg `control = Temperature_Controll2(client)`), then you would get an error regarding calling `__init__()` on `Echo`.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work? I need a more concrete solution please.

Comment: We all need concrete solutions, but stackoverflow is here to give answers to specific questions. As such, I can answer why you get your first error, but you're not going to like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error:

```
 AttributeError: 'ModbusTcpClient' object has no attribute 'modbus'
```

because when the `Thread` that you create:

`t2 = threading.Thread(target=control, args=(client, 'get'))`

calls `Temperature_Controll2.temp_controll(client, 'get')`,

on this line: `rp = self.modbus.read_coils(524, 0x1)` the `self`  is actually the `client` variable you created here:

`with ModbusClient(host=HOST, port=PORT) as client:`

and is not an instance of `Temperature_Controll2` that I assume you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps me a bit. How do I get the client.connect() into my member function, so how can I pass this. Should I instantiate this separately? I haven't been working with classes for long, so sorry for my stupid questions. In my thread 1, look at t1, the client instance is passed through (I think) via the SimpleWebSocketServer module?

Comment: What you need to do is to write a new question with the same code, except with this line: `control = Temperature_Controll2(client)`. This will produce a different error and you can quote the full error traceback in your question and that will get you one step further on.  This question can stand as an example of what happens when you try to call the method of a class without creating an instance first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you again, the solution is:

```
class Temperature_Controll2(Echo):

    def __init__(self, client):
        #super(Temperature_Controll2, self).__init__() #client , server, sock, address, database_reading)
        #super().__init__()
        self.modbus = client

    def temp_controll(self, value):
        #super().temp_controll(client)
        while True:
            print("temp_controll")
            rp = self.modbus.read_coils(524, 0x1)
            time.sleep(4)

def main():
    with ModbusClient(host=HOST, port=PORT) as client:
        client.connect()
        time.sleep(0.01)

        print("Websocket server on port %s" % PORTNUM)
        server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', PORTNUM, partial(Echo, client))

        control = Temperature_Controll2(client)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=control.temp_controll('get'))

        try:
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=server.serveforever())
            t1.start()
        finally:
            server.close()
```

But with client I can only make one connection to the modbus server, so either the websocket or the while loop works. I think I would have to approach the problem differently.

Comment: I don't think your `Temperature_Controll2` class needs to inherit from `Echo`. Also you are calling your `temp_controll` method, so the program will block there. You could use: `target=lambda:control.temp_controll('get')`

Comment: You're right this will work, that's brilliant, thank you so much!

Comment: Please allow me one more question, how is this to be understood with the inheritance, i.e. why does it not have to be inherited from Echo? Ok, super has been commented out, but how would one do that if it was needed in my case? (Theoretically)

Comment: You would could just delete the `__init__()` from `Temperature_Controll2` and then you would need to adjust the `control = Temperature_Controll2()` to supply the correct parameters.

Comment: Ah yes, I got this callback:  `TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'server', 'sock', and 'address'`

Comment: And if i don't comment out super though, then i get a similar error, i don't understand that, normally this should work with super().__init__() as well, so in case you would need this?

Comment: But you need `'server', 'sock', and 'address'` for the `WebSocket` class. Why does `Echo` need to inherit from `WebSocket`?

Comment: Echo inherits from Websocket so that methods from Websocket such as handlemessage can be used in the Echo class?... Ok, but I don't understand why methods from Echo can be executed from class Temperature_Controll2. Does the super(). cause methods or variables to be overridden. But without super, a method can still be executed? Sorry, these are stupid questions, I haven't been working with classes in python for that long.

Answer (score 0):

A short addendum, I think, I now know why the second variant does not work.

This variant is running until the temp_control in class Echo comes to the point, in which modbus modul was called by a funcion. Modbus module is not part of the mother class Echo, which is why I think this cannot be inherited.

Modbus is passed to the class Echo as a variable via partial and will thus instantiate (I hope I am expressing myself correctly). Therefore, only the variant in which the variable client is passed to the instance will work.

```
# This is a non-functional version of my programme and is for information only

class Echo(WebSocket):

    def __init__(self, client, server, sock, address):
        super().__init__(server, sock, address)
        self.modbus = client

    def temp_control(self)
        do_something()
        return True

class Temperature_Control3(Echo):

    def __init__(self, value=None): #, client, server, sock, address):
        #super(Temperature_Control3, self).__init__(server, sock, address) 
        if value is None:
            value = {}
        self.value = value

    def control(self, value):
        while True:
            self.temp_control(524, 'get')
            #self.database_reading()[0][1]
            time.sleep(2)


def main():
    with ModbusClient(host=HOST, port=PORT) as client:
        client.connect()
        time.sleep(0.01)

        print("Websocket server on port %s" % PORTNUM)
        server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', PORTNUM, partial(Echo, client))

        control = Temperature_Control3()

        t3 = threading.Thread(target=lambda:control.control('get')) 
        t3.start()

        try:
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=server.serveforever())
            t1.start()
            for thread in threading.enumerate():
                print(thread.name)
        finally:
            server.close()
```